# Adjusting layout of footer using fancyhdr

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr

Here is a minimal working example of what I'm trying to achieve in my footer.

[image]

I'm trying to get the footer rule to be roughly in line with the top of the `example-image-a`. The `lfoot` text (which consists of 4 lines) should roughly take up the same vertical height as the `rfoot` text (which consists of 3 lines in a slightly bigger font size).

My problem at the moment is that the `rfoot` has a big gap above it so it's way out of alignment with the `lfoot`.

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.2cm,footskip=1.1cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\lfoot{\parbox{0.7\textwidth}{\footnotesize TITLE GOES HERE \\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
}
\rfoot{\small \setstretch{1.3} Some text goes here \\ Some more text goes here \\ and more here 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [inner sep=0cm,outer sep=0,yshift=1.75cm,xshift=8.75cm] (picture)
        at (current page.south){\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

For full clarity, this is the layout I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

- The `rfoot` stays roughly in the same position.
- But the rule and the `lfoot` moves down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already loading and using `tikz` and `tikzpagenodes`, can't you simply use these packages to place the objects?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.2cm,footskip=1.1cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\lfoot{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,nodes={outer sep=0pt,inner
sep=0pt}]
\node[anchor=north west,font=\footnotesize,align=left,text width=0.7\textwidth] at 
([yshift=-6ex]current page text area.south west) {TITLE GOES HERE \\ Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.};
\node[anchor=north east,font=\small\setstretch{1.3},align=right,
text width=0.25\textwidth] at 
([yshift=-6ex]current page text area.south east){Some text goes here \\ Some more text goes here \\ and more here };
\node [anchor=north west] (picture)        at 
([yshift=-6ex,xshift=1em]current page text area.south east){\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}};
\draw ([yshift=-4.8ex]current page text area.south west) -- ([yshift=-4.8ex]current page text
area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\rfoot{}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion without `tikzpagenodes`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.2cm,footskip=1.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx, xcolor, ...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\lfoot{%
  \parbox[t]{0.7\textwidth}
    {\footnotesize
      TITLE GOES HERE \\
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
}}
\rfoot{%
  \parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    {\raggedleft\small\setstretch{1.3}%
      Some text goes here \\ Some more text goes here \\ and more here}%
      \rlap{\hspace{1cm}%
        \smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}{%
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [inner sep=0cm,outer sep=0]
            {\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}};
          \end{tikzpicture}%
}}}}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]